# Can`t use the response from a get request using callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, get-request

I make a get request from a url, and I try to use the response further, in another function, so this is what I tried first.

```
var request = require("request");

function getJSON(getAddress) {
    request.get({
        url: getAddress,
        json: true,
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            return body;
        }
     })
 }

function showJSON(getAddress, callback) {
    var test = callback(getAddress);
    console.dir(test);
}

showJSON('http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json', getJSON);
```

yet, when i run my script

```
node ./test.js
```

I get

```
'undefined' as a console message
```

I don`t know where this may come from, as I  am new to node.js, javascript

Comment: As I said, I am noy sure at all where this comes from. I would check this, hope it will answer my question. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var test = callback(getAddress);
```

is an asynchronous function

```
console.dir(test);
```

won't wait for it to finish before executing, hence you are getting undefined. to make it work you would have to do

```
var request = require("request");

function getJSON(getAddress, callback) {
    request.get({
        url: getAddress,
        json: true,
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            callback(body);
        }
     })
 }

function showJSON(getAddress, callback) {
    callback(getAddress, function(test){
        console.dir(test);
    });
}

showJSON('http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json', getJSON);
```

Comment: Any idea how can I modify my code to work?

Comment: @MirelIonutPuchianu Did you even took a look at the link I provided ? The answer is inside... (Hint : look at the accepted answer).

Comment: I edited the answer to be able to print the value of test

Comment: I was looking through it when marvel answered me, @NathanP.